# resource file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file

How can I use a .exe file in my resources folder? I want to copy the file in the resource folder to another folder.

tried this

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If (Directory.Exists("Files")) Then
    Else
    End If
    Directory.CreateDirectory("Files")

    Dim FileToCopy As String
    Dim NewCopy As String

    FileToCopy = My.Resources.THEFILEIWANT <- only this part doesn't work
    NewCopy = "Files\THEFILEIWANT.exe"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is needed so when ther file doesn't exists the file gets created/copied.

Does anyone knows how I can call the file from the resource folder?

Tried this `        Dim writePermission As FileIOPermission
        writePermission = New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write)

```
    If (SecurityManager.IsGranted(writePermission)) Then

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("Files", My.Resources.unscrambler, False)
    End If`
```

But I'm getting a invalid permission error.

Comment: so when the file does not exists the program can create it.

Comment: Don't they call that 'payload' in virus writer circles?

Comment: I don't know how the call it, i only know i need this, so when the file doesnt exists it creates it.

Answer (score 0):

I am still a beginner but I could suggest using a packer, such as the one included with **[CodePlex's Confuser](http://confuser.codeplex.com/)**. It packs multiple assemblies into one (as do all packers), and obviously, Confuser offers obfuscation, and is ***Free***.

*One warning!*** Packers have been known to raise alerts in Anti-virus software, so check your app with different AV software.

Hope this info is useful. :)